# Import in Orchard Cms just imports last record

Tags: xml, import, sql-server-ce, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am attempting to import data into Orchard CMS. 
I have a custom part, I have overridden Importing method in driver and I am using the Import/Export module.

I have exported some data from Orchard to ensure the XML schema is correct, but when importing only the last record is imported, no matter what data is on it.

I have also scrambled records in xml and the only imported one is always the last record the has an Id not null. So I can say the is not a problem of valid or invalid data. All records are valid and they will imported if they have an id (that will be replaced with next autogenerated key) and they are the last one in set.

No error whatsoever in logs.

I'm using Orchard 1.7.2.0 from git repository.

I'm using SQL compact as db engine.

Any idea why it is failing?

This is the part record:

```
public class VehiclePartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual byte VehicleRole { get; set; }
    public virtual string Identification { get; set; }
    public virtual string RadioCode { get; set; }
    public virtual int StartKm { get; set; }
    public virtual string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

This is the driver:

```
    protected override void Importing(VehiclePart part, ImportContentContext context)
    {
        var name = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "Name");
        if (name != null) {
            part.Name = name;
        }
        var vehicleRole = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "VehicleRole");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vehicleRole)) {
            part.VehicleRole = byte.Parse(vehicleRole);
        }
        var identification = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "Identification");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identification)) {
            part.Identification = identification.TrimEnd();
        }
        var radioCode = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "RadioCode");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(radioCode)) {
            part.RadioCode = radioCode.TrimEnd();
        }
        var startKm = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "StartKm");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startKm)) {
            part.StartKm = int.Parse(startKm);
        }
        var note = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "Note");
        if (note != null) {
            part.Note = note;
        }
        var startDate = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "StartDate");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startDate)) {
            part.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
        }
        var endDate = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "EndDate");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(endDate)) {
            part.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate);
        }
        var active = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "Active");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(active)) {
            part.Active = bool.Parse(active);
        }
    }
```

And this is the exported file that I have edited and I'm trying to import:

```
<!--Exported from Orchard-->
<Orchard>
    <Recipe>
        <Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
        <Author>admin</Author>
        <ExportUtc>2013-11-22T11:39:39.9566929Z</ExportUtc>
    </Recipe>
    <Data>
        <Vehicle Id="4" Status="Published">
            <VehiclePart Name="Fiat Punto" VehicleRole="2" Identification="EL 999 LV" RadioCode="013" StartKm="0" Note="" StartDate="2008-04-12T00:00:00" EndDate="" Active="true" />
            <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7066182Z" PublishedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7296195Z" ModifiedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7356199Z" />
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle Id="8" Status="Published">
            <VehiclePart Name="Fiat Punto" VehicleRole="2" Identification="EL 888 LV" RadioCode="014" StartKm="0" Note="" StartDate="2009-04-12T00:00:00" EndDate="" Active="true" />
            <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7066182Z" PublishedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7296195Z" ModifiedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7356199Z" />
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle Id="12" Status="Published">
            <VehiclePart Name="Fiat Punto" VehicleRole="2" Identification="EL 777 LV" RadioCode="017" StartKm="0" Note="" StartDate="2010-03-02T00:00:00" EndDate="" Active="true" />
            <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7066182Z" PublishedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7296195Z" ModifiedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7356199Z" />
        </Vehicle>
        <Vehicle Id="" Status="Published">
            <VehiclePart Name="Fiat Doblò" VehicleRole="2" Identification="DX 444 BL " RadioCode="051" StartKm="0" Note="" StartDate="2010-01-27T00:00:00" EndDate="" Active="true" />
            <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" CreatedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7066182Z" PublishedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7296195Z" ModifiedUtc="2013-11-22T10:27:57.7356199Z" />
        </Vehicle>
    </Data>
</Orchard>
```

Edited:

As per request this is the migration code that creates the db structure

```
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(
            "VehiclePartRecord",
            table => table
                         .ContentPartRecord()
                         .Column<string>("Name", c => c.WithLength(25))
                         .Column("VehicleRole", DbType.Byte)
                         .Column<string>("Identification", c => c.WithLength(12))
                         .Column<string>("RadioCode", c => c.WithLength(5))
                         .Column<int>("StartKm")
                         .Column<string>("Note", c => c.WithLength(255))
                         .Column<DateTime>("StartDate")
                         .Column<DateTime>("EndDate")
                         .Column("Active", DbType.Boolean)
            );


        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("VehiclePart",
                                                     builder => builder.Attachable());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
            "Vehicle",
            cfg => cfg
                       .WithPart("VehiclePart")
                       .WithPart("CommonPart", p => p.WithSetting("OwnerEditorSettings.ShowOwnerEditor", "false"))
                       .Creatable(false)
            );
```

Comment: Seems like your EndDate is not nullable. When the first import is done it should trigger an exception on the database. Could you fill that field and try it again?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have added a value to all startdate fields. All fields have a value now. No errors logged. Still same behavior: only last one is imported. I'm going to try import a different part part type and see if the problem is the same.

Comment: Could you edit your answer showing the migration and the data that is stored on the database?

Comment: I guess that you meant EndDate

Comment: Yes... I would say EndDate... yes, both end and start date have a valid value...

Comment: The database is currently empty... I have deleted all Vehicles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the code and the problem is on the id. The id shouldn't be empty and also should be something like this: Id="/Identifier=3cf393fcbdea4c4a9e881e74ce177735

With your id the dictionary always has the same key and it overrides the last one. I never used import/export module before, but I guess that these ids were set by you.

If you want to know more about this take a look at line 81 at DataRecipeHandler.

Comment: You suggestion pointed me in the right direction. It is not documented very well but for import/export a type that has not an autoroute attached one should add an identity part to it, that part then creates the unique id used in import. I do not see line 81 of RecipeStepExceutor because on my source stops at line 70...

Comment: I have resolved to do my custom import command instead of trying to match the complex xml that is generated... anyway your answer was helpful so I mark as answered as other may be find it useful. Have a nice day.

Comment: For other intereted in creating a custom import command have a look here: http://www.sarasota.me/blog/orchard-command-handlers-and-command-line-tools

Comment: upps sorry, I meant DataRecipeHandler instead of RecipeStepExecutor. Yes, for introducing custom data is better to do a command. Actually I'm doing it on a customer project, around 100k data rows from excels files. Have a nice day you too :)